# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException When Creating Deck of Cards in Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am hoping to get some help even though I know this is probably a very simple bug that I cannot seem to find an answer to.
 What I am trying to accomplish is to create a deck of cards, and I keep running into an out of bounds error.
 Here is my code:

Card Class:

```
public class Card {
    private String suit;
    private int face;

    public Card(int face, String suit){
        face = this.face;
        suit = this.suit;
    }

    public int getFace(){
        return face;
    }

    public String getFaceAsString(int face){
        int faceName = face;
        String faceString = "";
        if(faceName == 11){
            faceString = "J";
        } else if(faceName == 12){
            faceString = "Q";
        } else if(faceName == 13){
            faceString = "K";
        } else if(faceName == 14){
            faceString = "A";
        } else {
            faceString = Integer.toString(faceName);
        }

        return faceString;

    }

    public String getSuit(){
        return suit;
    }

    public void setSuit(String suit){
        this.suit = suit;
    }

 }
```

This is my main class:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hero_Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String[] suits = {"Spades","Clubs","Hearts","Diamonds"};
        int[] faces = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
        int index = 0;

        Card[] deck = new Card[52];

        for(int i = 0; i<suits.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<faces.length;j++){
               deck[index] = new Card(faces[i],suits[j]);
               index++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You switched the indexes for the faces and suits arrays in your for loops. It should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i<suits.length;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<faces.length;j++){
        deck[index] = new Card(faces[j],suits[i]);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will still throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because the code only allocates 52 items in the Card deck, but there will be 56 times through the inner and outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

You also have an extra number in your "faces" array - you're trying to create 14 * 4 = 56 cards instead of 13 * 4 = 52.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] faces = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
```

Get rid of **15** and do the loop as suggested by @Geshode

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have 14 faces instead of 13?

In any case, to more safely allocate the correct number of items in your deck array, use `int numCardsInDeck = suits.length * faces.length;` to calculate the total items in the deck.

Try this instead:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
    public static class Card {
        final int face;
        final String suit;
        public Card(int face, String suit) {
            this.face = face;
            this.suit = suit;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return face + " of " + suit;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] suits = {"Spades","Clubs","Hearts","Diamonds"};
        int[] faces = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
        int index = 0;

        int numCardsInDeck = suits.length * faces.length;

        Card[] deck = new Card[numCardsInDeck];

        for(int i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < faces.length; j++) {
                deck[index] = new Card(faces[j],suits[i]);
                index++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deck));
    }
}
```